# Is it possible to get 2 values in onNext() of subscriber in rxjava android?

Tags: android, rx-java

I've an observable like this

```
Observable.zip(observable, extObs, new Func2<List<UserProfile>, ArrayList<Extension>, UserProfile>() {
        @Override
        public UserProfile call(List<UserProfile> userProfiles, ArrayList<Extension> extensions) {


            return userProfiles.get(0);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Subscriber<UserProfile>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(UserProfile userProfile) {
            profileListener.onProfileSet(userProfile);
        }
    });
}
```

I need to pass the ArrayList in the method`profileListener.onProfileSet(userProfile);` as `profileListener.onProfileSet(userProfile,extensions);`

Is it possible to do so in zip or is there any other methods of rxjava to solve such type of problems?

Comment: If you can't do this, then you could just make a new object class to hold both the profile and the extension

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to do exactly what [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177239/is-it-possible-to-get-2-values-in-onnext-of-subscriber-in-rxjava-android#comment59989698_36177239) suggested in the comment.

For example like this:

1. Create a class that would represent combined results of your observables:

```
class CombinedResults {
    public UserProfile userProfile;
    public List<Extension> extensions;

    public CombinedResults(UserProfile userProfile, List<Extension> extensions) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }
}
```

*(Alternatively you could use [`Pair`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) class)*

2. Use an object of `CombinedResults` (or `Pair`) in your `Observable.zip` `Func2`.

```
Observable.zip(observable, extObs,
        new Func2<List<UserProfile>, ArrayList<Extension>, CombinedResults>() {
            @Override
            public CombinedResults call(List<UserProfile> userProfiles, ArrayList<Extension> extensions) {
                return new CombinedResults(userProfiles.get(0), extensions);
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<CombinedResults>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(CombinedResults combined) {
                profileListener.onProfileSet(combined.userProfile, combined.extensions);
            }
        });
```